# WebFaultException class in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, exception

I am working on a .net 3.5 REST WCF application.
I've found [WebFaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webfaultexception.aspx) is the best way to handle errors in REST services.
I can't seem to find the WebFaultException class in .net 3.5.
Was it introduced in .net 4 or am I missing a namespace import?
Is there a work around that implements WebFaultException behavior in .net 3.5?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like `FaultException` (which `WebFaultException` is derived from) is available in 3.5.  That's at least somewhere you can start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, `WebFaultException` was only introduced in the .NET 4.0 timeframe. Before that you were responsible for setting all of the HTTP properties on the `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse` and handling failure control flow yourself rather than relying on throwing exceptions.

That said, you can create your own `WebFaultException` class in 3.5 and then implement a WCF `IErrorHandler` that generically retrieves the HTTP information off your custom `WebFaultException` class and transfers them to the various properties of the `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse` and creates a `Message` instance for the body (if any) in the `ProvideFault` implementation.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your answer,I am using WebFaultException on my localsystem which has 4.0 framwork. When I am trying to test it using REST client add on for Firefox, I am getting The resource cannot be found error. Any idea.

Comment: No idea based on that limited info, sorry. Sounds like a new problem though, perhaps open up a new question about it with more details.